# VB database insert from 2 different servers

Tags: mysql, vb.net, db2

I am trying to insert data into one database (mysql) from a DB2 database that is not on the same server. I have searched for the answer,  but all I can find is the insert into db1 (select x from db2) method, but I cannot seem to make this work due to having 2 different connection strings to 2 different servers. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a one time only process or something that needs to be done multiple times? For a one time only process you could write the DB2 data to a file and then load it to MySQL with the LOAD DATA INFILE statement.

Comment: This is a process that will be ran on a weekly basis. In regards to writing the db2 data to a file, would that just be a .csv file?

Comment: Yes, both dbs have import/export utilities that can help (you want to do this as bulk loads).  You may want to investigate an ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) tool, some of which may be free.  I've heard DB2 has the ability to talk to other databases (on different boxes), but I don't know how to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench has a migration wizard.  I haven't tried it with DB2, but it does offer a variety of connections to other type of Databases including other RDBMS. I have tried the wizard with other database and it works great. I also creates scripts, which you could implement in VB.

Also, you could try IBM Data Studio. Here is a [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/59a36a54-50c8-4de0-a587-ec9eb47ceb5f/entry/how_to_use_export_import_load_in_data_studio_to_migrate_data_to_different_environment?lang=en)